# Oracle Sql Developer - IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establised the connection on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new for Oracle Sql Developer, When I tried to create a New connection it throws the below error in Ubuntu 16.04. I tried searching to find a solution for that but i didn't got any solutions yet.

> Status : Failure - Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: Make sure the listener is running on the server.  Also confirm your host, port and SID or service are correct - can you connect to it from sqlplus?

Comment: I'm trying **lsnrctl status** this is the command to know the listener status but it throws **lsnrctl: command not found** and also try this **sudo lsnrctl status**. @Joe

Comment: if the command is not found it's probably due to it not being in your path and/or you do not have it installed on your machine. Listener runs on the host machine, not necessarily where sqldeveloper is.Are you running SlDev from the same machine where the DB is running?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your oracle database as follows and test your connection.

[image]